# Neo4j performance on a fixed column table vs database performance

Tags: neo4j

I have a database table which I want to import into Neo4j. I was wondering how the performance of a standard indexed database table in postgresql would compare to neo4j (I know neo4j is not optimised for static table structures which is why I am asking).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends mainly on the operations you want to execute on that dataset. For set based operations postgres is certainly faster. But as soon as you go with data local operations and lots of joins Neo4j will be en par and faster than a relational database.

Criteria:

- data size
- number of joins
- local or global operations
- kind of operations (set based, projections, aggregations)
- are your operations expressable as graph traversals

If you can provide more details it might be possible to give a better answer. But the easiest thing is to try it on your own. Getting started with Neo4j is no issue and importing your dataset should be easy too.

HTH

Michael