# Graph / RDBMS hybrid?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, neo4j

What are your thoughts on using both Neo4j and a traditional RDBMS such as mysql?

I was wondering if keeping relationships/connections etc in Neo and messages/e-mails and security in mysql was a reasonable design.

Would this offer the best of both worlds? Neo would be optimized for relationships and mysql optimized for messaging?  Takes a bit of pressure off of each one - also allows sharding etc on the message and security side.  Also allows for smaller backup window for Neo4j, which, as I understand, must be taken offline to do..

What advantages and disadvantages do you see with such a system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only is this a perfectly reasonable approach, it's fully supported and documented in the Good Relationships guide (in case you're using Neo4j and MySQL through Spring).

http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/html/#reference:cross-store

It would certainly add complexity to your domain model and you would need to consider cross-store transaction handling in case you need to perform updates to both data stores within the same transaction.

Other than sharding/horizontal scaling (which is a something I hear Neo Tech is working on),  RDBMS would perform better if you need to run any iterative operation (such as an aggregation like SUM, COUNT, AVERAGE) over a large tabular set.

Related:
[Neo4j performance on a fixed column table vs database performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680182/neo4j-performance-on-a-fixed-column-table-vs-database-performance)

Comment: Thank you - I was also thinking about storing purchases/order information in mysql as well - not sure the graph offers any real advantage for that kind of data (transactional)..  Obviousy I haven't used Neo4j, but I don't want to go down a rabbit hole by adopting it now for everything when it may not bet the best tool for some parts of the system.. So before I adopt Neo, I want to see if a hybrid is a good solution... And I'm using Ruby on Rails with Active record and not spring - is that an issue?

Comment: I've only used Neo4j natively (Java) and through Spring but a Ruby driver is fully supported (https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j)

I suspect you may not get the cross-store persistence support you get with Spring but if you're not interested in splitting an object across two data stores and only storing relatinships in Neo4j and the attributes, etc. in another RDBMS you can easily manage persisting across both manually.

I use Neo4j as the first-class database (all objects and relationships) and MongoDB for messages/events. Clean separation - works like a charm.

Comment: Yea, I'd be ok with manually splitting things - I just need the id from Neo4j to store in the RDBMS I choose to link the two... More comfortable storing purchases and orders in RDBMS for a few reasons..Could use Mongo or Cassandra for messages - but will do that optimization later - at this point I'm just working on a prototype and messaging performance is not as important as news feed performance - rather focus on optimizing that at the moment.. Thank you..